# Извлечь текст из ячейки

Tags: google-apps-script

Нужно извлечь текст из ячейки.
в столбце находится список в виде текста `Name For Tb01 - 04/04/2018`, надо извлечь в соседнюю ячейку часть текста до тире `Name For Tb01`  и  в следующую ячейку дату `04/04/2018`
Извлекать текст из ячейки c помощью формулы получается, но возможно ли такое сделать с помощью скрипта? Подскажите пожалуйста скрипт.

Comment: А что мешает просто совместить скрипт с формулами? То есть скриптом проставить формулу, потом вставить данные как значения. Если чисто скрипт - смотрите в сторону split

Comment: В данном случае необходим скрипт, так как список очень большой, а растягивать формулу очень долго и список может быть разным.

Answer (score 2):

Все равно немного непонятно, чем Вам неугодили обычные формулы, поэтому опишу тут все 3 варианта:

### 1. Чисто формулы и автозаполнение

Допустим есть данные в столбце A.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рядом в ячейке B1 Вы пишете формулу: `=IF(ISBLANK(A1);"";SPLIT(A1;" - ";FALSE))` и просто клацаете 2 раза левой кнопкой мыши на нижний квадрат ячейки и она автозаполняется по количеству данных вниз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо можно использовать формулу массива с проверкой на пустые строки (чтобы не заморачиваться с указанием точного диапазона (тоже вводим в ячейку B1. Автозаполнять вниз не нужно.Так же не забудьте указать формат ячейки с датой как дату - иначе вместо нее могут быть цифры)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A);"";SPLIT(A1:A;" - ";FALSE)))
```

### 2. Скрипт + формула

Делаем то же самое, только введение формул не вручную, а скриптом. Так же можно вставить данные как значение (чтобы не было формул):

```
function myFunction10() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheetName")

  /* вариант с 1 формулой */
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow())
  var range2 = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 2)
  range.setFormula("=IF(ISBLANK(A1);\"\";SPLIT(A1;\" - \";FALSE))")
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  range2.copyTo(range2, {contentsOnly:true})

  /* вариант с 2 формулой */
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 2)
  var range2 = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 2)
  range.setFormula("=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A);\"\";SPLIT(A1:A;\" - \";FALSE)))")
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  range2.copyTo(range2, {contentsOnly:true})

}
```

### 3. Скрипт (работа с массивами)

```
function myFunction11() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheetName")

  var arrData = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues()

  var newArr = arrData.map(function(v,i,a){
    return v[0].split(" - ")
  })

  sheet.getRange(1, 2, newArr.length, 2).setValues(newArr)
}
```

Comment: 3. Скрипт (работа с массивами)
Без заголовка таблицы и если колонка первая работает, но если есть заголовок и не в первой колонке выдает ошибку:
Неправильная ширина диапазона: указано 1, должно быть 2
sheet.getRange(1, 7, newArr.length, 2).setValues(newArr)

Comment: Ну так Вы применяйте данное решение как основу и подгоняйте под свои нужды.

Comment: пробую, но не могу понять. где устанавливается эта ширина диапазона.

Comment: Обратитесь к первоисточнику. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)

Comment: уже пробовал:  var arrData = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getDisplayValues();, все разделяет, но выдает ошибку в строке (Неправильная ширина диапазона: указано 1, должно быть 2):    sheet.getRange(2, 2, newArr.length, 2).setValues(newArr)

Comment: Пробуйте "дебажить".  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting

Comment: Самое печальное, что вы рассматриваете, вывод текста, разделенного определенным символом, в разные ячейки. а мне необходимо извлечь часть текста в определенную ячейку.

Comment: Опять же - я ответил на Ваш вопрос - далее Вы сможете делать, что хотите. А как именно разделять строку - это уже как захотите. Почитать про основные действия со строками можно например здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ecczf11c(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, но к сожалению разбиение текста на столбцы мне не подходит, необходимо извлечь текст из ячейки. Если кто нибудь знает как это сделать подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Мда...Чтобы получать нужные ответы научитесь задавать правильные вопросы.

Comment: Вроде старался предельно ясно написать, "Извлечь текст из ячейки", или как то надо было по другому написать?